# Can a domain name be registered, but have it not appear on search engines?

Tags: dns

I need to make a personal website, but I don't want it appearing in Google or other search engines. I only want specific people to have access to it.

For example: if I buy www.example.com I want that the web pages to only be available to those who write in their browsers' URL bar that address. Not in search engines. Is that possible?

EDIT: I know about robots.txt. But that's for pages, not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the whole domain name to be available only to those who know it.

Comment: You could do a simple htaccess file with a passphrase that is known by those who know your domain. This would at least prevent "outsiders" from accessing your site from a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  When you register a domain name, it is public knowledge.  It will be impossible to keep it a secret.  The instant it appears in anything a search engine sees [facebook post, twitter message, ANYTHING], it will become "indexed".  All you can do, via `robots.txt`, is *ask* the search site to not crawl your site, but the name that got them there will still be indexed. (and, for the record, there are MANY crawlers that ignore everything in your `robots.txt`)

Answer (score 1):

The strictly correct answer is no, however you may be able to get a good part of the way there by (in addition to discouraging robots using robots.txt) get the webserver to look for a REFERER string, and behave the "Referer" is a search engine (or an unauthorised site).

Doing this depends on your server - you should be able to use mod_rewrite to match the REFERER variable if you are using Apache (Spelling is correct - its a bug in the standard).  There is nothing to stop someone from subverting this though, but it should catch a lot of automated sites.

Another solution might be to limit access to the server to your friends - for example by limiting to their IP addresses (or using a VPN), or even making sure they use specific, obscure browsers and checking for that.

Come to think of it though, the best way to do it might just be to password protect the entire site using .htaccess and give your friends the login credentials !